# ssh port-forwarding with GatewayPorts = no

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I want to forward sshd (port 22) on machine X which has a non-routeable IP.  The forwarding options are `nc` (which is horrible), `inetd` (requires privs), `iptables` (requires privs) and `ssh`.  So I'm using `ssh`, which has the added bonus of providing an encrypted tunnel.

I have a machine Y with a public IP.  I want to expose X:22 as Y:8022.

```
X $ ssh -R8022:localhost:22 Y
```

This works, but port 8022 is bound to the loopback:

```
Y $ netstat -ant
. . .  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8022          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

which means I cannot connect from any foreign machines.  Since `GatewayPorts` is `no` in Y's `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, I cannot specific another bind address.  Any ideas?

---

Note: I did manage to get things working by using **another** tunnel from Y to Y:

```
Y $ ssh -g -L9022:localhost:8022 localhost
```

which is a very inefficient solution: it encrypts/decrypts on `localhost` from port 9022 to 8022, then encrypts again before sending to X.  Surely there must be a better way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make ssh tunnel open to public?](http://superuser.com/questions/588591/how-to-make-ssh-tunnel-open-to-public)

Answer (score 1):

**since GatewayPorts is off, i haven't any solution** <-- comment from answerer themselves.

Why do you use a reverse port forwarding?

On host Y:

`ssh -f -N -q -L :8022:localhost:22 user@X` should do the trick

-f: daemonize

-N: no command

-q: quiet

-L: port forward

-: leading: `:` is used to enable local port via all interfaces, not only localhost

Comment: You can ssh from Y to X because (as noted in the question), X has a private IP.  This means a reverse tunnel is required.

Comment: ok, since GatewayPorts is off, i haven't any solution...sorry

Answer (score 1):

Try to run something like socat after connected to Y？

```
ssh -R8022:localhost:22 Y socat tcp-listen:9022,fork,reuseaddr tcp:127.0.0.1:8022
```

Then you can connect to X through Y:9022

Comment: can you confirm that this also works when Gatewayports is off?  Some terminal output demonstrating it would make this answer excellent.

Comment: yes this works when Gatewayports is off.
When `ssh -R8022:localhost:22 Y ` 8022 still bound to the loopback, then `socat tcp-listen:9022,fork tcp:127.0.0.1:8022` will relay any tcp connection to localhost:8088. socat 
 bind to 0.0.0.0 by default.
But this method requires addition tool `socat`.